# How to take 2 key board inputs to a 2 dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a 2D String array which stores name and address which are given as keyboard inputs.
eg: name 1 address 1;
    name 2 address 2;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String[][] array = new String[3][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {     
        array[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(array[0][0]);
  }
}
```

in here I want to print a statement asking to enter the name
eg. System.out.println("Enter name:");
after that I want to write another statement asking to enter the address
eg.System.out.println("Enter the address");
but i cant figure out how do that in a 2d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 2;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] array = new String[rows][cols];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        array[row][0] = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the address:");
        array[row][1] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    // Print out array
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            System.out.print(array[row][col] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print(";");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Person 1, Address 1, ; Person 2, Address 2, ; Person 3, Address 3, ;
```

Check it live here: https://onlinegdb.com/Byu4wc1vI

I hope this helps!

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot. and by the way i got another problem, if there are 'marks' insted of 'address' here is it possible to find the sum of marks in the array,because it is given as a string with person name how do find only the sum of 'marks'.?

Comment: You could make a variable outside the loop, for example `sum`, and then loop through your marks and do `sum += Integer.parseInt(array[row][1])`. Where `array[row][1]` is "marks"